# npm start is giving error and cache clean --force is not the solution for me

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to learn react. I have installed node 12.16.3 & npm 6.14.4 (LTS) 
Then I followed these steps

- `npm init`
- `npx create-react-app react_project`
- `cd react_project`
- `npm start`

First 3 steps worked just fine. But when I entered `npm start` it's giving me this error.

```
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.102/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from D:\Node project\react_project\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react_project@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react_project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lovem\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-11T06_29_57_551Z-debug.log
```

I have tried deleting npm modules and reinstall npm then `npm start` but didn't work.

Comment: It’s telling you the files and lines with errors in your error message.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you are talking about! Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in a DEV.To blog post

I have added %SystemRoot%\system32 in my environ Path & it solved my prb!
So Anyone facing the same problem i request to try this one!

Happy_Coding